# Javascript return only parent object that contain a special property

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

Suppose I have an object like following:

```
var Obj = {
             a: {
                   name: 'X',
                   age: 'Y',
                   other: {
                             job: 'P',
                             location: {
                                          lat: XX.XXXX,
                                          lng: YY.YYYYY,
                                          .........
                                       }
                          }
                }
          };
```

**My objective:**  I need a method that will check existence of a `key` and return its immediate parent object for any level of nesting.

**Example**  If I search for `lat` that method will return `location` object, if I search for `job` it will return `other` and so on.

Please help.
Thanks....

Comment: What have you got so far? (Hint:  try perhaps a recursive function that uses a for..in loop or jQuery's $.each()...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function findObjectWithProperty(obj, term){
    if (typeof obj == 'object'
        && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) !== '[object Array]'){
        for(var prop in obj){
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                if (prop==term)
                    return obj;
                var result = findObjectWithProperty(obj[prop], term);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Use:

```
var location = findObjectWithProperty(Obj, 'lat');
var other = findObjectWithProperty(Obj, 'job');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea of writing a generic function for this problem like Reflection in c#, but this funciton might help though not generic.

```
//Object.
var Obj = {
             a: {
                   name: 'X',
                   age: 'Y',
                   other: {
                             job: 'P',
                             location: {
                                          lat: 31.88,
                                          lng: 71.88

                                       }
                          }
                }
          };


function getParentObject(key,obj){  
  switch(key){
    case "lat" || "lng":   return obj.a.other.location; break;
    //write other cases...
    default:return obj;
  }
}


//Call
var lng = getParentObject("lat",Obj).lng;
```